# Who is FX45RTMGDR and why is he building .Net libraries?

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio

While adding references to my project, I noticed that some of the core .Net libraries are marked as "built by FX45RTMGDR" while others are not. What is this cryptic entity and why does it matter if it was built by it or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FX45RTMGDR is not a person or a machine, it is just a string that tells you a little bit about the file.  Here's the breakdown:

- **FX** - Framework (as in the .NET Framework)
- **45** - The version: .NET Framework 4.5
- **RTM** - Release to Manufacturing or a final, stable build of the framework.
- **GDR** - General Distribution Release or the build that was distributed to the public generally (as apposed to a Limited Distribution Release).

This [TechNet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2009/05/14/gdr-qfe-ldr-wth.aspx) explains a bit more about the other possible acronyms you might see in a file.